# setInterval not running on IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a simple setInterval call on my site:

```
var refresh = setInterval(refreshList, 30000);
function refreshList() {

    $.get("ajax/support/getSupportList.aspx", function (data) {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ticketList").html(data);
    });
}
```

This runs perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE it does not run at all.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: It is just speculation, but maybe the delay is too high?

Comment: Is it possible that the content of the page you're fetching is being cached? Try adding a random number or the current time as an argument to the end of the URL to test.

Comment: GET requests cache...Are you setting the right headers?

Comment: First replace the $.get with a simple alert and isolate the problem. I think that the method is being called.

Comment: ^^ was typing that, log something and see if the issue is the interval or the ajax (it's almost certainly the ajax).

Comment: `setInterval not running on IE?` - have you tried running just `setInterval()` in IE before you posted? This [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fXp3b/) works fine in IE as well. Always try an isolated demo before posting. The question being asked `setInterval not running in IE?` shows no research effort as it can be answered with the minimal of research using jsfiddle or just the debugger console.

Comment: The timer code is fine for IE. You are using a relative path for the ajax request (relative to the page it is running from). Run Fiddler2 and see if that is going to the right URL you expect it to.

Comment: Hi all, I replaced with an alert and that worked fine. Will try the Fiddler2 suggestion now. Weird though since Chrome and Firefox does not have an issue at all? Hmm..

Comment: *"This runs perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE it does not run at all."* Always narrow it down to figure out what part of it isn't running. Most likely you will find that all of it is running, it just isn't returning new html.

Comment: Ok, so Fiddler (thanks for the tip) shows that the correct page is called, and that a body of 1477 is returned (which I assume is page size), and when I called the same code from Firefix I also got 1477. So, why is the DIV not updated?

Comment: Hm ok.. It only fires ONCE in IE if the AJAX call is there, but if I replace with an alert it keeps firing. Anyone know why?

Comment: Replace `$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ticketList").html(data);` with `alert(data);` and see if you get the same data each time.